# Error while adding a row and then updating a row using EF

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

Currently I am attempting to add a new row to a database table through AJAX which is working fine. But then I try to update a different table and I get an error. Here is my code and the error I am encountering.

### Error

The object cannot be attached because it is already in the object context. An object can only be reattached when it is in an unchanged state.

Line 41:                     _db.ChampionCounters.Attach(champion);

### Code

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult VoteYes(int id)
    {
        string results;

        if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            var checkFirst =
                from c in _db.UserCounterLinks
                where c.counterId == id && c.userName == User.Identity.Name
                select c;

            if (checkFirst.Any())
            {
                results = "You have already voted on this counter.";
                return Json(results);
            }

            var userVoteLink = new UserCounterLink { counterId = id, userName = User.Identity.Name, userAgree = true };

            _db.UserCounterLinks.AddObject(userVoteLink);


            var champion = _db.ChampionCounters.SingleOrDefault(c => c.id == id);

            if (champion != null)
            {
                champion.positiveVotes++;
                _db.ChampionCounters.Attach(champion);
            }
            _db.SaveChanges();
            results = "Voted";
        } else
        {
            results = "You must be logged in to vote.";
        }

        return Json(results);
    }
```

### Summary

The code above is from the controller that handles the Ajax post. Like I said the userVoteLink table creates a record just fine. But when I try to update the other table ChampionCounters the error is thrown.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to attach the instance because the context is already tracking that instance. Just remove the `_db.ChampionCounters.Attach(champion);` line.